# TypeError: str.trim is not a function (Request-Promise/Tough-Cookie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, setcookie, request-promise, cookiejar

I am having similar problem as discussed here:
https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/183

I am using Request-Promise@4.2.2 and Tough-Cookie@2.3.4

And getting the same error:

> TypeError: str.trim is not a function

I also played around with npm-dedupe

[image]

Any clue,

My code looks like this:

```
let cookie = new tough.Cookie({domain: '.companyName.ninja',
  httpOnly: true,
  name: '_application_session',
  path: '/',
  secure: false,
  value: 'f044888d39e2d19126716d9f54028700' })
let cookieJar = request.jar()
cookieJar.setCookie(cookie, 'http://application.companyName.ninja/')
options.jar = cookieJar
```

Comment: You might want to try request-promise-native@1.0.5? I have it working with tough-cookie@2.3.4 (even when request-promise, which uses Bluebird instead of native promises, still is broken)

Comment: Are you missing the key when creating the Cookie?

Answer (score 14):

Change line

```
cookieJar.setCookie(cookie, 'http://application.companyName.ninja/')
```

to

```
cookieJar.setCookie(cookie.toString(), 'http://application.companyName.ninja/')
```

(use `toString()` method).